# how can I correctly finde the class name?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

sub, i have a big problem why i cant finde in the hml code the text with name "Auf Lager"?

I tried with finde class name and by xpath.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('Auf Lager').text;
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('Auf Lager').click;
```

but it doesn't work

[image]

Hope one can help me Thanks

Comment: The highlighted line does not follow proper syntax rules.

Comment: `Auf Lager` is not the class name.

Answer (score 1):

The `find_element_by_class_name()` method finds the first element by the class name. In your HTML, the class name is `"font-weight-bold"` which is inside a span tag. `Auf Lager` just the text in the span object.

So,

```
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("font-weight-bold").text;
```

will give you `"Auf Lager"`.

And, to click the first element holding the "font-weight-bold" class, use:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("font-weight-bold").click;
```

If you want to find the element by certain text in it, then try using xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "Auf Lager")]")
```